# The Javascript function call is not invoking the correct withFormat option in Grails controller

Tags: javascript, grails

I am calling a method in a Grails controller from Javascript.  I am using Grails 2.3.9.

```
function renderCalendar() {
    $("#calendar").fullCalendar({
        events: '/calendar/list',
        contentType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        header: {...
```

The code in the controller is:

```
withFormat {
    html {
        [calendarInstanceList: eventList]
    }
    json {
        render eventList as JSON
    }
}
```

However, the json closure of the request.withFormat is not executed.  Not sure why.

Also, I have tried this in the Javascript:

```
function renderCalendar() {
    $("#calendar").fullCalendar({
        events: '/calendar/list.json',
        contentType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        header: {...
```

and this does not call the controller in question.

I also tried several contentType parameters:

```
contentType: "text/json",
...
contentType: "JSON_CONTENT_TYPE",
...
contentType: "text/json",
```

I also enabled mime headers in Config.groovy:

```
grails.mime.use.accept.header = false
```

Here are the mime types in my Config.groovy:

```
grails.mime.types = [html: ['text/html', 'application/xhtml+xml'],
        xml: ['text/xml', 'application/xml'],
        text: 'text/plain',
        js: 'text/javascript',
        rss: 'application/rss+xml',
        atom: 'application/atom+xml',
        css: 'text/css',
        csv: 'text/csv',
        pdf: 'application/pdf',
        excel: 'application/vnd.ms-excel',
        rtf: 'application/rtf',
        ods: 'application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet',
        all: '*/*',
        json: ['application/json', 'text/json'],
        form: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        multipartForm: 'multipart/form-data'
```

Comment: unless the `format` is specified, the default format (whichever is declared first, in this case `html`) will be used. Either move `json` closure above `html` closure, or call `/calendar/list.json`.

Comment: Did you intend to use `contentType: 'application/json'` instead of `contentType: 'json'`?  Also, the mimeTypes defined in your Config.groovy may be relevant.